# How to make the Zig build system emit a c-header along with a generated library

Tags: build, zig, c-header

Calling `zig build-lib -femit-h my_lib_source.zig`, a c-header file can be exported for a library written in zig.

How can the same be achieved in `build.zig`?

Could this be achieved with an option to b.installArtifact?

I found no documentation about this at https://ziglearn.org/chapter-3/.

Comment: Unfortunately, build.zig format changes with every release. What is your zig version? `zig env`

Answer (score 1):

I looked into this a bit and I believe getEmittedH is currently broke. Maybe it works if you're also compiling an exe from a .c file (like the official documentation shows) but compiling a zig library by itself getEmittedH() puts the .h in the wrong directory (see this GitHub issue: https://github.com/ziglang/zig/issues/18497).

Adding

```
_ = lib.getEmittedH();
```

after

```
   b.installArtifact(lib);
```

does create the .h, but it's in the root of zig-cache.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've created a lib compile step as `const lib = b.addStaticLibrary(...)` you can write

```
const install_header = b.addInstallFile(lib.getEmittedH(), "include");
b.getInstallStep().dependOn(install_header);
```

which should install the generated header file into a folder called `include` inside `zig-out`

Comment: I tried this, but `install_header` has the wrong type. Using the line `b.getInstallStep().dependOn(&install_header.step);` instead, the build script fails with `install generated to include: error: unable to update file from '<some_folder>\zig-cache\o\a40ed50705e9642e32a189965ec7b5e8\pitch_detection.h' to '<some_folder>\zig-out\include': FileNotFound`
Is there something else which need to be done, in addition (manually creating the folder `include` inside `zig-out` didnt work).

Comment: I am building a shared lib btw.

Comment: when changing to a static lib, the error message is different: `zig build-lib pitch_detection Debug native: error: the following command exited with error code 116:
zig.exe build-lib <some_folder>\src\pitch_detection.zig -femit-h --cache-dir <some_folder>\zig-cache --global-cache-dir <user_folder>\AppData\Local\zig --name pitch_detection -static --listen=-`

Comment: without the two added lines, my build script works fine in the dynamic and static case.